# Programmatically insert Textbox into Scrollview

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, xamarin, renderer

```
    public class CustomEditorRenderer :  EditorRenderer{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement == null) return;
            Element.Focused += ElementOnFocused;
            Element.Unfocused += ElementOnFocused;
            SetScrolling(Editor);
        }

        private void SetScrolling(CustomEditor view){
          //TODO Custom scrolling?
        }
}
```

I was planning on trying something along the lines of:

```
var scroll = new ScrollViewer();
scroll.Content = Control;
```

However, I am not entirely sure on how to place the scrollview into the view since the `parent` attribute can't be set. I was hoping to do:

```
var parent = Control.Parent;
scroll.Parent = parent;
Control.Parent = scroll;
```

Bear with me as I am also very new to Windows development and may be missing something. If it helps, I am not using XAML, it is all a MVVM implementation with programmatically created views. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347066/programmatically-adding-content-to-scrollviewer-scrollbar-stops-working

Comment: I can't do the exact same implementation, however that link you posted gave me a decent idea to try. I'll post it as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around, I may have found a possible solution.

```
private void SetScrolling(CustomEditor view){
    var scroll = new ScrollViewer{Content = Control};
    var index = Children.IndexOf(Control);
    if(index != -1)
        Children.RemoveAt(index);
    Children.Add(scroll);
}
```