# StackPanel is not scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to put lots of controls inside a `StackPanel` and user can scroll up and down. I have a simple `StackPanel` inside a grid.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If I'm not wrong, I've seen that `StackPanel` scrolls, but now it is not working. Does it support scrolling or it is not supported at all? ( I prefer not to put it inside a `ScrollViewer`). thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802821/how-can-i-get-scrollviewer-to-work-inside-a-stackpanel

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really scrolls unless it has a ScrollViewer inside. When you do it like you're doing it now, you'll see only the items that fit on the screen, and others will be 'out of screen borders'.

So I'm afraid you'll have to add a ScrollViewer. It's actually a good thing that StackPanel doesn't scroll by default.

Comment: thanks igrali. my problem with `ScrollViewer` is that when I pull down it, it shrinks and app black background appears. this is not good when I have an image as the background