# WPF DataGrid extends beyond Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Been looking at it for 4 hours, guys...  I just can't figure this out (possibly Microsoft bug?)

This is what I have and it's all good except DataGrid control.  As you can see in this video, data goes beyond app's boundary (grid and scroll bar):

https://goo.gl/photos/YnApkZS7v3uZ4TWX6

Since this code is using Material Design library, I stripped it down to basics so that anyone could try it out for themselves.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="EvolvDirectoryCreeper.MainWindow"
    Height="700" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="80"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Height="180" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid Margin="10,10,100,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Height="40" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" Padding="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label Content="Good" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,30,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Bad" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,30,0,0"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BadFoldersHistory}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And this is C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace EvolvDirectoryCreeper
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> m_badFoldersHistory = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> BadFoldersHistory
        {
            get { return m_badFoldersHistory; }
            set { 
                m_badFoldersHistory = value;                                                                           
                OnPropertyChanged("BadFoldersHistory");
            }
        }

        public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        private Dispatcher MainWindowDispatcher;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            MainWindowDispatcher = Dispatcher;

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                BadFoldersHistory.Add("d");
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried "Auto" instead of "*" in the last row of each Grid but doesn't help.  I need to keep this Grid structure to maintain Material Design FAB location and proper resizing.
ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you need to define height. I gave the first RowDef to 180, since your first grid is 180.Try the below code.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="80"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Height="180" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid Margin="10,10,100,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Height="40" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" Padding="0,15,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label Content="Good" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,30,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Bad" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,30,0,0"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BadFoldersHistory}"  />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yep!  That's what it is!   Thanks!

Comment: By the way, anyone interested in Material Design WPG library, I highly recommend this: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be to put a control that could show the `content` if exceeding the height of parent control. It's a very common problem with the `ContentControl` like controls(like `Window`,`ContentControl` or any `Panel` etc) in WPF.

[See this link to see the generic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802821/how-can-i-get-scrollviewer-to-work-inside-a-stackpanel/35293080#35293080)

> We can't be sure of Height of inner controls all the times so a fix
>   height solution is not the best solution. If a control height exceed
>   or match the height of your `grid` then a fix height solution is kaput.

A generic solution is contain your `grid` in a control that can handle variable height(like **`Scrollviewer`**). Like below:

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualHeight,Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid>
............
</ScrollViewer>
```

And you don't have to worry about any control's height being exceeded from the height of your `grid/Window`.

**Output:**

[image: ScrollViewer]